# VBA - Copy a sheet to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a sheet (sheet2) from certain workbooks (paths in cell column "B") to another workbook (template).

I tried the following one but Excel Return me the following error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error".

```
Private Sub SplitFile_Click()
  Dim C As Integer
  Dim x As Variant
  Dim Z As Workbook

  For C = 0 To 10

  Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C)
  Worlbooks.Open("x").Sheets(Sheet2).Range("A1:U1000").Copy
  Set Z = Workbooks.Open("D:\PTP\MASTERDATA\SPACCHETTAMENTO FILE\TEMPLATE.Template.xlsx")


  Z.Sheets("SPLIT TAB").Range("A1:U1000").PasteSpecial
  Workbooks("Z").SaveAs Filename:="PROVA.xlsx"
  Next C
End Sub
```

Can you help me?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: `Z` is already a workbook and does not need the Workbook wrapper:

Comment: So: `Z.SaveAs Filename:="PROVA.xlsx"`

Comment: Please take a minute to take the [tour] ;)

Comment: A lot is wrong here.
1. You start the loop with C = 0 which will yield an invalid range (B0) the first time the loop is exectuted.
2. "x" is a literal string, but I think you need to use the Object variable X which points to a range, so Workbooks(x.Value).Open is the right syntax
3. Sheet2 is a literal string so needs quotes "Sheet2"

Comment: @jkpieterse good catches. FWIW `Sheet2` might actually be an automatically created global-scope object referring to `ThisWorkbook.Sheet2` (which of course is going to go up in flames when you do `.Sheets(Sheet2)`; every sheet in an Excel VBA project can have a "code name", an identifier that you can use in code to refer to that sheet, e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles")` could have a `(name)` property of `SelectedFilesSheet` and then you can do `x = SelectedFilesSheet.Range("B" & C)`. Also `x` being assigned with `Set` makes `x` a `Range` object, which makes `.Open(x)` feel wrong.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I saw x is a range object so deliberately added the (default) .Value property to it. I don't like depending on the default property of an object (which is slower as well).

Comment: @jkpieterse absolutely agreed!

Answer (score 0):

VBA is blowing up on this line:

```
Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C)
```

Because the value of `C` is 0, and 0 isn't a valid row number - `B0` isn't a valid range address. So you could start with `C = 1` and that would fix *this* error.

I'd strongly recommend using a `Long` integer (32-bit) instead of an `Integer` (16-bit) when referring to row numbers (regardless of which rows you need). The maximum value of an `Integer` is 32,767, and a worksheet can have many more rows than that.

`x` is declared as a `Variant`. This means it can be/become literally anything you make it.

If you do this:

```
x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C)
```

Then `x` will contain the value of the cell referred to by the `Range` call.

However you did this:

```
Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C)
```

This instructs VBA that `x` should contain an *object reference*, so instead of assigning it the *value* of the cell, you're getting *the cell itself*.

Then you do this:

```
Worlbooks.Open("x").Sheets(Sheet2).Range("A1:U1000").Copy
```

If this compiles, it's only because `Option Explicit` isn't specified. `Worlbooks` doesn't exist anywhere, it's a typo - but because `Option Explicit` isn't specified, VBA allows you to use variables without declaring them, and so happily compiles `Worlbooks` and defers its resolution to run-time... at which point *another* error will pop up.

This would fix it:

```
Workbooks.Open("x").Sheets(Sheet2).Range("A1:U1000").Copy
```

Except... it's inside the loop: at every iteration of that loop, you try to open a workbook named `"x"` (which most probably doesn't exist). If `"x"` means to be a file name contained in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C)`, then `x` should be declared as a `String` variable, and you would refer to it like this:

```
Dim source As Workbook
Set source = Workbooks.Open(x)
```

And you would do that *outside the loop*, so that you don't try to open the same workbook every time the loop makes an iteration: IIRC opening a workbook that's already opened will throw yet another run-time error.

If each iteration should be working with a different workbook/file, then each iteration should also close that workbook, otherwise you end up with 12 workbooks opened, 11 of which you don't need anymore.

So you keep a reference to the workbook object you want to work with:

```
For C = 1 To 11
    x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C).Value
    Set source = Worlbooks.Open(x)
    source.Sheets(Sheet2).Range("A1:U1000").Copy
    '...
    source.Close
Next
```

Same with your *destination* book:

```
Set Z = Workbooks.Open("D:\PTP\MASTERDATA\SPACCHETTAMENTO FILE\TEMPLATE.Template.xlsx")
```

You're opening the same file 11 times, and not closing it once. And then you paste from the *source* book into that *destination* book...

```
Z.Sheets("SPLIT TAB").Range("A1:U1000").PasteSpecial
```

...overwriting the previous iteration's work everytime, and saving 11 times.

---

So, there's *a lot* of serious issues in that code. Recap:

- Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.
- Declare all variables, with an explicit specific type whenever possible.
- Clean up after yourself.

Learn to use the debugger. <kbd>F9</kbd> sets a breakpoint, which stops execution; from that point on you can use <kbd>F8</kbd> to run your code one instruction at a time, and you can use the *immediate pane* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) to output anything in the current execution context. Use the *locals* toolwindow to visualize everything the current scope has access to.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to copy and paste data between Workbook as it will run more slowly. Here some example code, hope it can help you..!

```
Option Explicit

    Public Sub SplitFile_Click()
      Dim C As Integer
      Dim x As Range
      Dim Z As Workbook

      For C = 1 To 10
          Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedFiles").Range("B" & C)
          Set Z = Workbooks.Open("D:\Template.xlsx")

          Z.Sheets("SPLIT TAB").Range("A1") = x 'this code is faster that copy & paste
          Z.SaveAs "PROVA" & C & ".xlsx" 'workbook should have a unique filename

          Z.Close 'close workbook
      Next C
    End Sub
```